# Android view Pager flip more pages on swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, carousel, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using ViewPager with FragmentStatePageAdapter to show a number of views where user can go through. With current implementation **only one page is changed at any single swipe**. Instead I want to **flip through multiple views based on user swipe**. If swipe is long/fast i need to flip through multiple views and vice versa.

here is my current code

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter 
{
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ItemFragment.init(position);
        }


    }
```

PageContainer class

```
public class PagerContainer extends FrameLayout implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private ViewPager mPager;
    boolean mNeedsRedraw = false;

    public PagerContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public PagerContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public PagerContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        //Disable clipping of children so non-selected pages are visible
        setClipChildren(false);

        //Child clipping doesn't work with hardware acceleration in Android 3.x/4.x
        //You need to set this value here if using hardware acceleration in an
        // application targeted at these releases.
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        try {
            mPager = (ViewPager) getChildAt(0);
            mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The root child of PagerContainer must be a ViewPager");
        }
    }

    public ViewPager getViewPager() {
        return mPager;
    }

    private Point mCenter = new Point();
    private Point mInitialTouch = new Point();

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mCenter.x = w / 2;
        mCenter.y = h / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        //We capture any touches not already handled by the ViewPager
        // to implement scrolling from a touch outside the pager bounds.
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mInitialTouch.x = (int)ev.getX();
                mInitialTouch.y = (int)ev.getY();
            default:
                ev.offsetLocation(mCenter.x - mInitialTouch.x, mCenter.y - mInitialTouch.y);
                break;
        }

        return mPager.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        //Force the container to redraw on scrolling.
        //Without this the outer pages render initially and then stay static
        if (mNeedsRedraw) invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mNeedsRedraw = (state != ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);
    }
}
```

How can I do this in android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change the view by calling:

```
ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int index)
ViewPager.setCurrentItem(int index, bool animation)
```

You must handle the sliding commands yourself, but on a certain slide you cloud call [setCurrentItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) of the ViewPager. The setCurrentItem method also allows you to enable or disable animations.